# how to replace "/" on path string with "\/" using sed?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, sh

I've tried this:

```
PATH="/user/dj/a/mydir"
PATH_FORMAT=`echo "${PATH}" | sed 's/\//\\\//'`
```

but it only replace the first "/".
I want the resulting PATH_FORMAT value to be:

```
"\/user\/dj\/a\/mydir"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You seem to be missing a backslash, see latest edit in my answer.

Comment: Why do you need to have this replacement? I've never seen good uses of such things...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a `g` flag to your substitute command:

```
echo "${PATH}" | sed 's/\//\\//g'
```

Or more readable, as per *Jonathan Wakely* in the comments:

```
echo "${PATH}" | sed 's:/:\\/:g'
```

To achieve what you describe in your question, you need one more backslash:

```
echo /user/dj/a/mydir | sed 's:/:\\\/:g'
```

Output:

```
\/user\/dj\/a\/mydir
```

Comment: Also, you avoid [leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) if you pick a different delimiter: `echo "${PATH}" | sed 's:/:\\/:g'`

Answer (score 3):

Use Bash's parameter expansion, if you are running a shell script:

```
MYPATH="/user/dj/a/mydir"
PATH_FORMAT=${MYPATH////\\/}
```

The substition `${parameter}` is extended by the syntax `${parameter//pattern/string}` which replaces *all* patterns found in `parameter`.
The `pattern` can be a regular expression.
In your case, the `pattern` is: `/`. The replace `string` is: `\\/`.

Furthermore, **avoid storing something in the variable `PATH`**, because it is probably used by the system -- unless you want to modify the system's path variable.

Quoting [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)'s manual on parameter expension:

> **${parameter/pattern/string}**
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string. The match is performed according to the rules described below (see Pattern Matching). **If pattern begins with `/`, all matches of pattern are replaced with string.** Normally only the first match is replaced. If pattern begins with `#`, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter. If pattern begins with `%`, it must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter. If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may be omitted. If the nocasematch shell option (see the description of shopt in The Shopt Builtin) is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of alphabetic characters. If parameter is `@` or `*`, the substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Answer (score -2):

```
sed "s%/%\\\\\\/%g"
```

.
As Simple as that

Comment: please give more detailed instructions